# How to read a text file with a web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I want to create a web service that takes a text file as parameter and returns the content of that file.

This web service will then be used by a C# client.

This is what I have so far (webservice):

```
[WebMethod]    
public String txtFile(String filename)
{
   StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename);   
   {
      String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
      return line;            
   } 
}
```

and(client):

```
WebService ws = new WebService();
ws.txtFile("textfile.txt");
```

When I run the client I get UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: What error is displayed?

Comment: Define "crashes".  What is the error?  In what way does it fail?

Comment: throw some breakpoints in there; check that file exists before trying to read it; wrap your reading logic in try...catch

Comment: You sure the file exists in the default application path?

Comment: Side note: returning content of the file from server by name is really dangerous idea. In real life please make sure there are some permission checks in place before reading and returning file to caller (unless you are writing root kit).

Comment: Oftentimes there are security issues accessing files on a web server.  Our server admins wouldn't let me have access to just any path given all the compliance issues out there these days.  That said, this may or may not be applicable to the solution you are building

Comment: Since I haven't caught the exception it simple crashes (with no error info...)

Comment: @Mechk: Then catch the exception.  Error messages contain useful information.

Comment: Surround the call with a try/catch.  Then log the exception

Comment: Ok so it seems @Rob A was right. The exception that I get is UnauthorizedAccessException. How do I resolve this? This whole project is on my localhost using IIS

Comment: right click security tab and add the identity you are using, personally speaking on my local I just add everyone

Comment: All the users have full rights for that textfile

Comment: If you're running the web service in IIS the web service doesn't magically run as your user. Unless you have Windows Authentication turned on for your application, the web service will access files using the Application Pool Identtity and that identity must have permissions to the file.

Comment: @JamieSee that was indeed the issue. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Ok. I'll post it as an answer so you can close the question then. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue was that the current IIS user didn't have permission to access the file (not even read).

And apparently the web service will use Application Pool Identity and not the current (windows)user (unless you have Windows Authentication turned on for your application).

Follow these steps to add permission for application pool:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Select a file or directory
3. Right-click the file and select "Properties"
4. Select the "Security" tab
5. Click the "Edit" and then the "Add" button
6. Click the "Location" button and make sure you select your machine
7. Enter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the "Enter the object names to select:" text box
8. Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK"

Answer (score 2):

you sending only the file name, then how service check your local file from server by the file name!

You need to give full path to file name, like network path or file server path. and that path should be accessible for the web service running user.

but if you change the method as below and send the file content with file name you can save it to server.

```
[WebMethod]
public void Upload(byte[] contents, string filename)
{
    var appData = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var file = Path.Combine(appData, Path.GetFileName(filename));
    File.WriteAllBytes(file, contents);
}
```

Comment: The path for the file was just an example (the actual path was indeed correct). And I only wanted to read from the file (and not save it on the server)

Answer (score 1):

Add some logging in your web service, and dump to the logging framework the input parameters and the exception details ( yes, you should add a try-catch in the web service ).

before you do this:

```
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filename);
```

also check:

```
if(!File.Exists(filename))
{
  // dump to the log file the file was not found at the location... filename
  return string.empty;
}
```

then you can do:

```
using(var sr = File.OpenText(filename))
{
  string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
  return line;
}
```

finally, mind the fact that passing a relative path from the client to the server does not mean anything, you should probably verify that only a network path can be specified, the C or D drive or any other locally mapped drive/path in the calling client might be not accessible or access something different on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the web service in IIS the web service doesn't magically run as your user. Unless you have Windows Authentication turned on for your application, the web service will access files using the Application Pool Identtity and that identity must have permissions to the file.

Answer (score 0):

`File.OpenText` can throw many different exceptions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx  (I'd start by making sure the path is in the right format)

`StreamReader.ReadToEnd` can throw an **OutOfMemoryException** or an **IOException**.  See reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx